# Data Matrix Code always 12x12

Tags: java, zxing

The following code saves an Image with the size 12x12 whereas I am defining the BitMatrix with width 500 and height 500. What is wrong with my code?

```
DataMatrixWriter dmw = new DataMatrixWriter();
BitMatrix bm = dmw.encode(code, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX, 500, 500);
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/test2.jpg"));
    MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bm, "jpg", fos);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (fos != null) {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the data you are encoding does not need to be larger than this.

Answer (score 0):

As i see in source code of DataMatrixWriter.encode() method, arguments *width* and *height* are not used for barcode generation at all. They just checked to be non-negative, so they obviously has no any meaning.